# How best to send complex data with FCM / GCM using Go

Tags: json, go, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

Both the FCM and GCM documentation give the structure of the `data` payload as a map[string]string (although [google's GCM package](https://github.com/google/go-gcm) implements it at a map[string]interface{})

However, there are many cases where a simple flat key:value structure doesn't meet the needs of an application.  Some examples are when a slice of values is needed, or when another non-trivial struct needs to be sent.

What would be the cleanest way of sending more complicated data structures as a map[string]string?

---

Conclusion:  I have marked the answer by fl0cke as correct given that it provides a solution to sending complex data with FCM / GCM using Go.  However, it is clear from the FCM documentation, that the intention is for the data to be key:value string pairs moving forward, and so to be sure that nothing gets broken in the future, I will be sticking to simple key:value string pairs.

Comment: Hi, can u please advise me where i can get the sample code implementing  gcm-go package..  i have been trying it but not getting any sample code

Comment: @RajeevKumar I'm not aware of any official sample code, but there are quite a few blogs posts / tutorials on it if you use your Google-fu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378004/with-android-gcm-can-you-use-a-deep-json-data-field) answer, it is possible to send nested data with FCM/GCM.
To do that, you can write your own FCM Client or fork google's implementation and change the type definition of `Data` from

```
type Data map[string]interface{}
```

to

```
type Data interface{}
```

And plug in any type that is JSON serializable (e.g. nested structs).

---

It is also possible to send the data via a JSON string without changing the type definition of `Data`:

```
// first marshal your complex data structure
complexData := someComplexStruct{...}
b, _ := json.Marshal(complexData)

// then assign the returned json string to one key of your choice
data := map[string]interface{}{"key":string(b)}
```

You probably have to unquote the json string before parsing it on the client.

Comment: The requirement in the FCM docs (not the library) state that `data` has to be a set of key value pairs.  Is that inaccurate?

Comment: @JohnGB According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378004/with-android-gcm-can-you-use-a-deep-json-data-field) answer it is possible to send nested data.

Comment: Is there any confirmation from Google that they will support this?  All documentation that I can see specifically states that they should be key value string pairs.

Comment: You can still serialize your data to a json string and send it that way, if you want to be 100% sure. I will update my answer with some suggestion later.